# Finding nearest neighbor pixel from a binary mask

Tags: python, opencv, breadth-first-search, flood-fill

I have a matrix and a binary mask. For example:
Matrix is

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15, 16]])
```

And binary mask is

```
array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1]])
```

I want to create a new matrix that has original matrix's entries in places where the binary mask is 0, and in nonzero places it should choose the closest element from the zero region. So the required output matrix in the example above is:

```
array([[10, 10, 11, 11],
       [10, 10, 11, 11],
       [10, 10, 11, 11],
       [14, 14, 15, 15]]).
```

Using opencv, I can obtain a matrix of distances for the binary matrix, via the command:

```
cv2.distanceTransformWithLabels(binary.astype('uint8'),cv2.DIST_L2 ,cv2.DIST_MASK_PRECISE)
```

The output of the command is

```
(array([[2.1968994, 2.       , 2.       , 2.1968994],
        [1.3999939, 1.       , 1.       , 1.3999939],
        [1.       , 0.       , 0.       , 1.       ],
        [1.       , 0.       , 0.       , 1.       ]], dtype=float32),
 array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1]], dtype=int32))
```

However, it does not return the indices of closest element, only the distances from it (as can be seen in the example above). Any idea how to achieve the desired output using `opencv` or any other python package?

Comment: How do you want to handle a case where there are multiple nearest neighbours? For instance,
```array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]])```

Comment: @VBB I'm OK with choosing any of the nearest neighbors if there are several (I also don't mind to get their average if it is somehow easier)

Comment: this could be approached as inpainting, path finding, distance transform (and following the gradient to an edge pixel), ... you already found DT with labels, so try `DIST_LABEL_PIXEL`

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz DIST_LABEL_PIXEL just change the distances to array([[3., 2., 2., 3.],
        [2., 1., 1., 2.],
        [1., 0., 0., 1.],
        [1., 0., 0., 1.]], dtype=float32). But it doesn't give me the output matrix I specified in the question. Maybe I'm not using it correctly? I use cv2.DIST_LABEL_PIXEL instead of cv2.DIST_L2 in the command from my question